# CSS Snap Scroll Not Working Smoothly with Mouse Wheel, but Works with Keyboard Arrows

Tags: css, scroll-snap

I'm encountering an issue with CSS Snap Scroll where it doesn't scroll smoothly when using the mouse wheel, but it works perfectly fine when using the keyboard arrows.

Is there a way to make it work smoothly with the mouse wheel as well? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

I have 5 sections inside the html tag.

```css
html {
    scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
}


section {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    scroll-snap-align: start;
    scroll-snap-stop: always;
}
```

```html
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar">
      <img
        src="assets/navbarIcon.svg"
        alt="navIcon"
        class="navIcon"
        width="25"
        onclick="toggleNavMenu()"
        id="nav-toggler"
      />
      <ul class="navLinks nav">
        <li><a href="#inicio" class="active">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#semillas">Semas</a></li>
        <li><a href="#sobreNosotros">Nosotros</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contacto">Contacto</a></li>
        <li><a href="#preguntas">Preguntas Frecuentes</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="navbar navbarMenu" id="nav-menu">
      <ul class="navbarMenuLinks nav" id="nav-links">
        <li><a href="#inicio">Inicio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#semillas">Semas</a></li>
        <li><a href="#sobreNosotros">Nosotros</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contacto">Contacto</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <section id="inicio" class="flex flex-col justify-center items-center">
        <header class="header">
          <img
            src="./assets/Logotipo_CamaloteSeeds_SinFondo-09.png"
            alt="logo"
            width="160"
            id="nav-logo"
          />
        </header>
    </section>
  
    <section id="semillas" class="overlay">
        <div class="info">
          <div class="info-img">
            <img
              src="./assets/images/Genética camalote logo-20.png"
              alt=""
              class="logo-genetica"
            />
          </div>
          <div class="info-img">
            <h1 class="texto-genetica">
              Conocé todas las <strong>características</strong> de nuestras
              semillas.
            </h1>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="swiper">
          <img
            src="./assets/images/Flechas-25.png"
            class="flechas flecha-izq prev-btn"
          />
          <img
            src="./assets/images/Flechas-26.png"
            class="flechas flecha-der next-btn"
          />
          <div class="swiper-wrapper">
            <!-- Slide-start -->
            <div class="swiper-slide">
              <img
                src="./assets/images/Tarjeta Genéticas-28.png"
                alt=""
                class="seeds-img"
              />
            </div>
            <!-- Slide-end -->
            <!-- Slide-start -->
            <div class="swiper-slide">
              <img
                src="./assets/images/Tarjeta Genéticas-29.png"
                alt=""
                class="seeds-img"
              />
            </div>
            <!-- Slide-end -->
            <!-- Slide-start -->
            <div class="swiper-slide">
              <img
                src="./assets/images/Tarjeta Genéticas-27.png"
                alt=""
                class="seeds-img"
              />
            </div>
            <!-- Slide-end -->
          </div>
          <div class="swiper-pagination">
            <div class="swiper-pagination-bullet">
              <img src="./assets/images/navegadores-22.png" alt="" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </section>
  
    <section id="sobreNosotros">
        <header class="headerNosotros">
          <img
            src="./assets/Logotipo_CamaloteSeeds_SinFondo-09.png"
            alt="logo"
            width="160"
            id="nav-logo"
          />
        </header>
        <div class="info-nosotros">
          <div class="quienes-somos">
            <h1 class="title">¿Quiénes somos?</h1>
            <p class="text">
              Somos un grupo de amigos de Santa Fe con más de 6 años de
              experiencia como cultivadores y 3 años como criadores de semillas.
              Hemos registrado nuestra variedad en INASE y ahora somos criadores y
              fitomejoradores de categoría A. <br class="text-br"> Estamos emocionados de anunciar que
              hemos comenzado a vender oficialmente nuestra genética al público,
              ofreciendo nuestras semillas de manera legal en growshops y a
              aquellos que tienen REPROCANN.
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="foto-expo">
            <img
              src="./assets/images/Nosotros/galería imágenes-35.png"
              class="img-galeria"
              id="caca"
            />
            <img
              src="./assets/images/Nosotros/texto fotográfo créditos-36.png"
              class="img-creditos"
            />
            <button class="ver-mas-btn">
                ver más
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
    </section>
  
    <section id="contacto">
        <header class="header-contacto">
            <img
              src="./assets/Logotipo_CamaloteSeeds_SinFondo-09.png"
              alt="logo"
              width="160"
              id="nav-logo"
            />
        </header>
        <div class="contenedor-contacto">
          <div class="container-wrapper">
            <div class="form-wrapper">
              <form class="form-contacto">
                <h2>Hola! <span class="empecemos">Empecemos</span></h2>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Tu nombre">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Asunto">
                <textarea  placeholder="Mensaje"></textarea>
              </form>
            </div>
            <div class="redes-contacto"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@11/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
```

Snap Scroll is working fine, except for not having that smooth effect that does have when using the arrows or clicking an <a> link to go to another section.

Comment: Can you share some sample HTML as well to make this into a[Minimal Reproducible Example](//stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Click the button in the toolbar that looks like `[<>]` to add a code snippet to your question.

Comment: @ChrisBarr done it! Thanks for the guidance.

Comment: This snippet reproduces the issue you are describing? For me It auto-scrolls to the `logo`.  I can use the mouse wheel or arrow keys to go to the other sections but I can never get to the navigation links above, it scrolls me away from those.  Keep in mind that your `script.js` file (and all the images) are not able to be linked here. You will have to add those separate if they are important for this demo.

Comment: @ChrisBarr this is weird because I just tried the snippet and it works fine. When i use the mouse wheel, it scrolls down smoothly. However, that's not how it's behaving in the page itself. It does scroll down to the other sections, but not smoothly. I read that it could be a Chrome issue.

Comment: That could be. I was using Firefox. I just tried it in chrome and it basically works the same but it is a bit more jittery, but not bad.